# Windows 8.1 Universal apps documentation

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am trying to develop universal app for first time. This may be a silly question, but is there any comprehensive documentation for c# developing? I need to partially migrate windows 8 app to universal app, but everything I need to use is different there and nowhere I can find what to use instead. It takes hours to find something useful. Mostly here or at other forums. MSDN is not very helpful in this case. I found that universal apps do not use .net framework or silverlight. Is possible to say that universal apps uses clearly labeled standard, for example .net framework 4.5? In this time it seems to me I have to use something from Windows Runtime apps and something from Windows Store apps APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for:

Windows universal apps use Windows Runtime.

Only reliable official "MSDN like" page I found is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211369.aspx

Good tutorials are at Channel 9.

Answer (score 2):

The MS Virtual Academy offers free courses (mostly jumpstarts) for things you might be interested in.

Below is a link to their jumpstart course:
Developing Universal Windows Apps with HTML and JavaScript Jump Start
    http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-universal-windows-apps-with-html-and-javascript-jump-start

And a link to their jumpstart course:
Programming in C# Jump Start
http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developer-training-with-programming-in-c

Hopefully, this will get you started.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong to express, I started already. I made few simple apps, but for older versions of Windows. In Win 8.1 I am not sure, what to use. I cannot find any "changelog" or something like that. For example, what to use instead WebClient? There is HttpClient, but it lacks any events, which I badly need. There is WebWiev, which has events, but does not the same as WebClient...